# How do determine gutter-width in the sass version of zurbs foundation

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Should be relatively simple, by I can't quiet figure it out.

I have this:

```
.parent
   @include grid-row()


.main
    @include grid-column(8)

.sidebar
    @include grid-column(4)
```

The elements 'main' and 'sidebar' end up sitting right next to each other with no gutter.

I can see in the grid docs that there is a variable called $column-gutter, and that it has a default setting. But I can't see it's effect.

In the file _grid.scss I can see $column-gutter. It has a default value, and I have touched it. But it has no effect on side-by-side elements in a row. These elements have no gutters.

So how do I make use of that variable, or otherwise set gutter widths?

Comment: Could you put your HTML plz?

Comment: My current test sass and html can be seen here:
http://pastie.org/7746183 It's different from my original: instead of a main and a sidebar, it has 3 columns. However, the issue is the same: there are no gutters.

Answer (score 1):

You should set values of the configuration variables prior to importing Foundation.

See http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configurable-variables/ :

> Many Compass modules use guarded assignment to allow you to set defaults for that module. In order for these configurable variables to work correctly, you must set the variables before you import the module. For example:
>
> > $blueprint-grid-columns = 12
> >
> > @import "blueprint/grid"
>
> Because of this, it is common to have one or more partials that set the constants first and get imported before any other imports in your stylesheet(s). This is commonly referred to as the "base" stylesheet and is usually named `_base.scss` 
>   or _base.sass.

Comment: Just try the suggestion @bob.

Comment: I've run a test with the variable set first. There doesn't seem to be a change.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and in my case the problem was that I was never actually using the _settings.scss file.  And since this was the case, none of my changes were being reflected on the site.

If this is the same for you, then what you need to do go to the screen.scss file, make sure its calling `@import "app"`. Once this is confirmed, go to the app.scss file and at the top make sure you call `@import "settings"`.  Once you do this, the settings in the _settings.scss file should actually cause an affect on the gutter settings that you want to change.

Comment: By 'screen.scss', I assume you mean my sass file, from which I'm including the foundation files and defining my own styles. I've got no idea what "app" is, and it isn't mentioned in the foundation docs for grid. I found _settings.scss and included it, uncommenting the $column-gutter line and rebuilding my css file. There is no difference in the layout.

Comment: app.scss is not really necessary its just the file in which all of the individual foundation components can be included.  From what I can see from your pasted code, the only thing I could think of at this point is that you are actually not importing the file settings.scss file.  Are you sure that it is in the same directory as your sass files? Or is it in another directory?  If so you will just have to change the directory path in the import.  Otherwise, I can't really think of too much else unless I see more code.

Comment: File paths aren't a problem. Otherwise 'sass --watch' would complain.  I made another example with three columns with the same gutterless problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rFnio. Sass code: http://pastie.org/7750073