# how do I set columns with gutters in the sass version of foundation?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm having trouble getting columns to work with the sass version of foundation.

I'm trying to create 4 columns within a row.

The parent is set to be a row. The four children are given this rule:

```
@include grid-column(3)
```

My expectation is that this should create four columns, because `12 / 4 = 3`.

However, the last column doesn't sit in the row, and a gap is left.
What is happening here?

Here is what I have:

My sass source : [LINK](http://pastie.org/8345336)

Resulting html/css : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G89GA/)

edit: 
stackoverflow generates an error if I link to jsfiddle without pasting code here. So here is my html:

```
 <section id="main-content"

        <section id="looptest">

          <h2>foundation/sass columns</h2>

          <div id="blocks">

            <div class="block">
              <p>block one</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
              <p>block two</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
              <p>block three</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
              <p>block four</p>
            </div>

          </div><!-- ENDS #blocks -->

     </section><!-- ENDS #looptest -->

  </section>  <!-- main-content ends -->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do determine gutter-width in the sass version of zurbs foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291093/how-do-determine-gutter-width-in-the-sass-version-of-zurbs-foundation)

Comment: Hey Leon. Nope. My question is unrelated to that question. And the solutions aren't applicable either.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting `#blocks` to `@include grid-row` only. Instead you are setting it to also `@include grid(12)`. It also looks like you are nesting the `.block` class. This could also be causing issues.

Think about it in relationship to the presentational classes. This is especially important since the presentational classes are in fact being generated by the very same sass and sass mixins.

For example, using presentational classes it should look like this

```
<div class="row" id="blocks">
    <div class="large-4 columns block"></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns block"></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns block"></div>
</div>
```

So, your sass should mimic this same structure. Right now it might look like this (minus the nesting):

```
<div class="row large-12 columns" id="blocks">
    <div class="large-4 columns block"></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns block"></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns block"></div>
</div>
```

Also keep in mind if you use nested grids, you will always need a `row` div to enclose your `columns`

So a simple 3 column layout would be like so:

```
<div id="blocks">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

and the sass in the simplest sense would be:

```
#blocks
  @include grid-row
.block 
  @include grid-column(4)
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I'm doing. And it's a good instructional on how to use the grid mixin. However, the issue with your code remains that same as with my code: there are still no gutters. This is the case even if I remove the '@include grid(12)', as you suggest.

Comment: Since the gutters are defined by padding rather than by margins on those divs, you need to nest another div within the "column/.block" and then set the background-color of that div to get the effect of the grid with gutters. Otherwise it appears to be aligned flush. This only has to be done if your columns differ from the background-color below them. i.e. in [emmet shorthand](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/) `.row>.large-4.columns*3>.panel>` or in a similar format to your sass `#blocks>.block*3>.block-content>`